# input stream from aws S3 into Rcpp

Tags: r, amazon-s3, rcpp

I have .txt file named **test_file.txt** in my AWS S3 bucket stored in the location 
**s3://path/to/csv/test_file.txt** which contains a sample statement like - *this is for testing*

I can read this file directly from the S3 bucket location using a combination of readLines and pipe statement in R as

```
df <- readLines(pipe("aws s3 cp s3://path/to/csv/test_file.txt -"))
df
#[1] "this is for testing"
```

When I try to replicate the same in Rcpp, I write a file rcoo_input_string.cpp as follows

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::String rcpp_input_test() {
  Rcpp::Environment base = Rcpp::Environment("package:base");
  Rcpp::Function readline = base["readline"];
  Rcpp::Function as_string = base["as.character"];
  std::string input_string = Rcpp::as<std::string> (as_string(readline("> "))); 
  Rcpp::Rcout << input_string << std::endl;
  return input_string;
}

/*** R
library(magrittr)
rcpp_input_test()
*/
```

Note:I got the idea that std::cin wont work in R or Rcpp, so I took inspiration from this post [Getting user input from R console: Rcpp and std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300471/getting-user-input-from-r-console-rcpp-and-stdcin)

I write another file rcoo_input_string.R as follows

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("./rcoo_input_string.cpp")
```

and execute the rcoo_input_string.R file from the AWS CLI as

```
aws s3 cp s3://path/to/csv/test_file.txt - | Rscript rcoo_input_string.R
```

but I get the following output on the CLI

```
> library(magrittr)

> rcpp_input_test()
>

[1] ""
```

which means that the Rcpp function did not read the **test_file.txt**.

Please note that running

```
 sourceCpp("./rcoo_input_string.cpp")
```

runs perfectly well and I can give the input and the Rcpp function returns the string value as well (like this)

```
> sourceCpp("./S3_to_R_data_import/rcoo_input_string.cpp")

> library(magrittr)

> rcpp_input_test()
> this is for testing
this is for testing
[1] "this is for testing"
```

Can someone guide me on how to create an input stream for this function in R ?
I say input stream, and please correct me if I am wrong, because I wrote a similar code for a C++ file and it executed perfectly.

Note: In trying to solve this problem, I tried cppFunction too, but that did not not solve the problem. Example of rcoo_input_string_2.R

```
library(Rcpp)
#sourceCpp("/mnt/legoland/S3_to_R_data_import/rcoo_input_string.cpp")
cppFunction(' String rcpp_input_test() {
  Environment base = Environment("package:base");
  Function readline = base["readline"];
  Function as_string = base["as.character"];
  std::string input_string = as<std::string> (as_string(readline("> "))); 
  Rcout << input_string << std::endl;
  return input_string;
}
            ')
print(rcpp_input_test())
```